# Why is final subscriber never executed?

Tags: java, rx-java2

When the below code is run, the final subscriber is never executed. Why?
I am using rxJava 2.1.0; I suspect there is some monkey business with threading, but struggling to figure this out.

My actual goal is to combine (reduce) all Struct instances that have the same value for id field into a single instance of Reduced and then pump it down the pipe.

```
   @Test
   public void experiment2() throws InterruptedException {

      PublishSubject<Struct> publishSubject = PublishSubject.create();

      publishSubject.buffer(3000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, 10000)
              .flatMap(Observable::fromIterable)
              .groupBy(Struct::getId)
              .flatMap((GroupedObservable<String, Struct> t) -> {
                  return t.reduce(Optional.<Reduced>empty(), (Optional<Reduced> accumulator, Struct str) -> {
                     if (accumulator.isPresent()) {
                        accumulator.get().all.add(str.patternId);
                        return accumulator;
                     } else {
                        Reduced fresh = new Reduced();
                        fresh.all.add(str.patternId);
                        return Optional.of(fresh);
                     }
                  }).toObservable();
              })
              .filter(Optional::isPresent)
              .map(Optional::get)
              .subscribe((Reduced t) -> {
                 //WHY IS THIS NEVER REACHED???
                 System.out.println(t);
              });

      publishSubject.onNext(new Struct("sig1", "A"));
      publishSubject.onNext(new Struct("sig1", "B"));

      Thread.sleep(60000L);
   }

   public static class Reduced {
      private final Set<String> all = ConcurrentHashMap.newKeySet();

      @Override
      public String toString() {
         return all.toString();
      }
   }

   public static class Struct {
      private final String id;
      private final String patternId;

      public Struct(String id, String patternId) {
         this.id = id;
         this.patternId = patternId;
      }

      public String getId() {
         return id;
      }

      public String getPatternId() {
         return patternId;
      }
   }
```

Comment: It might crash but you don't see it due to lack of `onError` handler in `subscribe()`. If not, you can start putting `System.out.println` to the callbacks and/or add `doOnEach` at various points to see where data gets lost.

Comment: If you filter on `isPresent()` then your Optionals might be empty and you simply might not have any data left to pass to `subscribe`. Have you tried moving around the `subscribe` in the call chain to figure out which step it fails on? You could also try using a `blockingSubscribe()` call to rule out potential async shenanigans.